# My PC has problems noticing drives and booting Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios

The PC might suddenly notice the drive if I connect it with another device using just one cable or maybe two cables or do anything else that shouldn't have an effect on the pc like swap cables with dvd player. Also if i connect the devices in some magical way which i cant remember now windows 8.1 will boot.

It never saw all devices at once.I always have to do lots of trial and error to make it notice a different drive instead what it sees now much less see all of them.It probably somehow keeps corrupting all my hard and usb drives.Only 2 out of about eleven work now.Now it doesnt even see my 2 160gb drives at all.Seagate ST3160021A surely spins up at boot unlike the SATA WD1600JD.I can't hear the WD1600D spin maybe it is too quiet?But it always worked until I didn't use it for some time.

The weirdest is that I installed windows 8.1 and it worked until I attempted to connect my dvd drive and it gives me an error which looks exactly like this but maybe the error code ending is a bit different.

[image: http://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/Imgs/Windows1_BCD_err.png]

**To mys surprise Windows 8.1 booted OK after I somehow *magically* connected it exactly like it was before.I think that even if I'd get the exact config as then it wouldn't work anyway probably because this PC is absolutely impredictable.**
I have been trying and no success.I thought I had luck because when windows 8.1 worked I made a recovery drive.Unfortunately it didn't do anything.Just like the install dvd.I also tried <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> sveral times.The only windows install dvd that works is XP.The problem in that is I can't update from Xp to Windows 8.1 (I found out after many hours of failure because the error code didn't bring me up any results in search engines) so I upgraded to Win 7 from xp just to 7->8.1 because the pc wont boot from these windows cds

**I've already wasted many fortnights in LOTS OF STRESS FRUSTRATION with this PC.Please explain this weird PC behavior and why it effects Windows 8.1 boot.**

The devices are:

- WD1600JD is a SATA drive.All the rest are PATA.
- Wd400something with windows 8.1 enterprise on it.
- Maxtor 40gb with Win 7 Ultimate on it.Became corrupted suddenly after a few power cycles.
- optiarc dvd drive burner
- cd drive burner GCE - 8520b

connected to MS-6702 motherboard. aka K8TNEO FSR-FIS2R.I updated Bios to the latest and last version 7.1 they will make for this board.I can't find any firmware updates for the drives except for the cd and dvd but I don't have access to Windows to flash them.

Comment: Can you tell us what your hard drives are (size, connection type, how they are connected to the motherboard and what is installed on them)?

Comment: WD1600JD is sata.Wd400 is pata. like the maxtor 40gb and optiarc dvd drive burner and cd drive burner GCE - 8520b

Comment: Can you provide a description, or an illustration/picture of how these drives are connected in the PC? That will help us understand what Windows is seeing when booting.

Comment: They are coonected using PATA cables and legacy power connectors.I tried to use jumpers and a SATA power connector too.I have about five of those cables.When I wrote that I try connecting them with one cable I meant that thecable has 3 pata ports.One goes into the motherboard MS 6702 aka K8T NEO FSR-FIS2R.I updated to the latest and last BIOS version they will make for this old PC.I'd like to update the drive firmware but thre never was any or it cant b found anymore except ofr the cd and dvd drive.

Comment: Do you know which drive you have installed Windows 8.1 on?

Comment: On the wd40gb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I had the same motherboard once!

First, let's try and get Windows 8.1 to boot successfully.

1. Disconnect all the hard drives (data and power cables).
2. Check the WD40GB drive and make sure it is set to be the master drive. There will be little jumpers on the end with the connectors that should have instructions on how to set master or slave.
3. Plug in the power to the drive
4. Plug in the PATA cable to IDE1 port (the one closest to the memory slots)
5. Plug the connector at the END of the PATA cable into the WD40GB.
6. Start the computer and let us know what happens.

Comment: I currently hate this motherboard.I only connect to the yellow PATA ports next to each other.Are these two ports normal?It looks like there used to be another port a bit lower but there isnt any.I'm very surprised and happy that you actually had this motherboard because maybe you have experience with this problem

Comment: I have windows 8.1 installed on the WD40gb drive

Comment: OK I'll be right back.